# How many よろしくお願いします to say during job interview?

Tags: culture

Let's say I have an interview with 3 people. Each interviewer does self-introduction followed by よろしくお願いします. When they say it I say it too, kind of, in response. Then I say my self-introduction and say the phrase. Then we start to discuss different topics and sometimes I feel it is a right moment to say it again.

My question is when is the right time to say it? Do I say it each time interviewers say it? Do I say it only at the end of my self-introduction or it does not matter and I can say it whenever I feel like it without any penalties?

よろしくお願いします!

Comment: I'm not sure about the formality of interviews, but you might want to consider 謙譲語　よろしくお願いいたします.

Comment: I think 42 times is your best bet.

Comment: I'd say that it's up to you how often you say it, depending on the type of person you are. I'd probably skip out on saying it after they introduce yourself, then wait until you introduce yourself before you say it, then probably once at the end of the interview. Just pick whatever is most comfortable without overdoing it. In your example interview, it's fine to say it the first two times then once it's over maybe, but I'd probably shortcut repeating it during the discussion unless there's a strong reason to say it. Some people use it more than others, so use it when you feel comfortable to.

Comment: Tthanks everyone for the tips! It is much clearer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, like what *Nothing* commented,  you'll want to use よろしくお願いいたします instead of よろしくお願いします.

> You'll only need it to say it during your self-introduction and upon entering the interview room.

In all seriousness though, you'll need 失礼いたします a lot more than よろしくお願いいたします. Though this isn't what you're asking, I'll just leave this here:

1. Before you enter the interview room. If there's no response after knocking a few times, say 失礼いたします and enter.
2. When you open the door, open it only slightly and say 失礼いたします again when you see your interviewer(s).
3. Just before you sit - when you're beside your sit, please say 失礼いたします again before sitting (please wait for them to tell you to sit first! It's usually something with ~お掛け下さい).
4. After your interview ends, stand beside your chair and say 失礼いたします again.
5. And again before you open the door to leave the room.

Comment: Yuu-san, thanks a lot for the answer!